# Automatic Information Transfer Between Databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2010

I have an application which uses an Access Database to store records.  This application is a third party application and cannot be altered but I do have the ability to open the database and view all the records it creates.

What I would like to know is this - Is there a way to tell Access to send new records to a table in a SQL database when the record is created in Access.  This needs to be done without any user intervention.  In the perfect world this application would talk directly to SQL, but I would settle for a less than perfect world if the software continues to talk to Access and then Access talks to SQL.

Comment: You said "This application is a third party application and cannot be altered..." which means you would need an external means of grabbing new data. Yes, you could create another Access database, link it to the table, have a timer that monitors for new data. However, that is not the same as a trigger that fires 'on new record'.

Answer (score 1):

Access 2010 did introduce event-driven [data macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) which behave like triggers. An After Insert data macro can create records in another local Access table, but unfortunately

> Queries that contain linked tables, action queries, and database references are not allowed in data macros.

so you cannot use an After Insert data macro in Access to "push" new records into a linked SQL Server table.

However, you could use a scheduled job in SQL Server to "pull" new records from an Access database that has been set up as a Linked Server in SQL Server. For example, say we had a table named [Inquiries] in Access

ID - Autonumber (Incrementing), Primary Key
InquiryDate - Date/Time
ContactName - Text(255)

and a corresponding [dbo].[Inquiries] table in SQL Server

ID - int, Primary Key
InquiryDate - datetime
ContactName - nvarchar(255)

We could set up the Access database as a Linked Server named ACCDBDATA in SQL Server and then have SQL Server run a scheduled job every so often to pull new records from the Access database using a T-SQL statement like this

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Inquiries (ID, InquiryDate, ContactName)
SELECT ID, InquiryDate, ContactName
FROM ACCDBDATA...Inquiries
WHERE ID > (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM dbo.Inquiries)
```